# EF5 Code First navigation property multi-property map with enum values

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Given the following model:

```
public class Item
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<File> Attachments { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ObjectType ObjectType { get; set; } // enum stored as INT
  public int ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

How would I describe the `Item.Attachments` navigation property using Fluent API so the resulting SQL joins correctly, such as:

```
SELECT ... FROM Items a 
LEFT JOIN Files b
  ON a.Id = b.ObjectId AND b.ObjectType = 8 (example enum value)
```

I've tried exposing `Item.ObjectType` and `Item.ObjectId` properties and then doing the following in my Item map:

```
HasMany(x => x.Attachments)
  .WithOptional()
  .Map(x => x.MapKey("ObjectType", "ObjectId"))
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

But this results in the following runtime error, presumably because this isn't an actual foreign key in the database.

> The specified association foreign key columns 'ObjectType, ObjectId'
>   are invalid. The number of columns specified must match the number of
>   primary key columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported in code first mapping because your relation between `Item` and `File` is not valid referential constraint. EF code first supports only mappings equivalent to foreign key constraint => columns in foreign key of dependent table must match columns in primary of principal table. Your case expects additional constant column in dependent table.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but couldn't find any concrete evidence it wasn't supported.  Hopefully this will be supported in the future because it's been a somewhat common scenario for me (where one type can be related to many other types) and using the enum scales better than having a separate join table for each type.